# Global Count inside recursive function

Tags: python

I watched a video about the Hanoi Tower, and followed along to create the script to solve it. The code runs just fine, but I wanted to add a counter in the function, so that I could print each step with an index, to follow along.
I tried using a global variable to count the amount of times the recursive function is called, and the use this count as my index, but still can't get it to work properly... What am I doing wrong in here?

```
count = 0


def tower(n, start, end, middle):
    global count
    if n == 1:
        count += 1
        print('%i - Coloque o disco %i do pino %s no pino %s' % (count, n, start, end))
    else:
        count += 1
        tower(n - 1, start, middle, end)
        print('%i - Coloque o disco %i do pino %s no pino %s' % (count, n, start, end))
        tower(n - 1, middle, end, start)


tower(5, 'A', 'C', 'B')
```

And now the output is something like this:

```
5 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
5 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino A no pino B
6 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
6 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino A no pino C
8 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
8 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino B no pino C
9 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
9 - Coloque o disco 4 do pino A no pino B
12 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
12 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino C no pino A
13 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
13 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino C no pino B
15 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
15 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino A no pino B
16 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
16 - Coloque o disco 5 do pino A no pino C
20 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
20 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino B no pino C
21 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
21 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino B no pino A
23 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
23 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino C no pino A
24 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
24 - Coloque o disco 4 do pino B no pino C
27 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
```

Can someone explain me why the counter isn't working the way I inteded?

Comment: For `n > 1` you first increment "count", then make a recursive call which increments again and prints "count", returns and then same count is printed in the calling function (actually this goes over multiple recursion levels). Solution: Increment "count" only directly before printing.

Comment: The recursive calls to `tower()` are changing `count`, of course - so you're seeing the wrong value because your `print` is after the first recursive call.  You'd need to copy the value to a local variable before the call to get the expected values.

Comment: Once you see this, it's obvious. However, you could have found this yourself if you had stepped through the code in a debugger. Try to find a video tutorial on how to use one, this is something you absolutely want to learn!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, it really helped me to understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you just start printing things when you have n == 1 since it's a recursion, but you add the count every time the recursion is called.

You can fix that by just moving the count add to before the print in the else statement like this:

```py
count = 0


def tower(n, start, end, middle):
    global count
    if n == 1:
        count += 1
        print('%i - Coloque o disco %i do pino %s no pino %s' % (count, n, start, end))
    else:
        tower(n - 1, start, middle, end)
        count += 1
        print('%i - Coloque o disco %i do pino %s no pino %s' % (count, n, start, end))
        tower(n - 1, middle, end, start)


tower(5, 'A', 'C', 'B')
```

And it will output as following:

```py
1 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
2 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino A no pino B
3 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
4 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino A no pino C
5 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
6 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino B no pino C
7 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
8 - Coloque o disco 4 do pino A no pino B
9 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
10 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino C no pino A
11 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
12 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino C no pino B
13 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
14 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino A no pino B
15 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
16 - Coloque o disco 5 do pino A no pino C
17 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
18 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino B no pino C
19 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
20 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino B no pino A
21 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
22 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino C no pino A
23 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
24 - Coloque o disco 4 do pino B no pino C
25 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
26 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino A no pino B
27 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino C no pino B
28 - Coloque o disco 3 do pino A no pino C
29 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino B no pino A
30 - Coloque o disco 2 do pino B no pino C
31 - Coloque o disco 1 do pino A no pino C
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably shorter to repeat the condition rather than repeat the counting and printing:

```
conta = 0
def tower(disco, doPino, noPino, tempPino):
    global conta    
    if disco>1: tower(disco - 1, doPino, tempPino, noPino)
    conta += 1
    print(f'{conta} - Coloque o disco {disco} do pino {doPino} no {noPino}')
    if disco>1: tower(disco - 1, tempPino, noPino, doPino)
```

By placing the print and count in between the two recursive calls, everything that needs to be done prior to moving disc `n` from `start` to `end` will be printed (and counted) before the move itself is printed. And every other moves that need to happen after are printed by the second recursive call.  When `n` is 1, there are no discs on top, so the function simply prints and counts the single move.

In this case, the first call is to move disc 5 from 'A' to 'C'.   But prior to that, every disc that is on top of disc 5 needs to be moved to 'B'. So we let the first recursive call do that.  Then we print the move (disc 5 from 'A' to 'C').  This leaves a pile of discs (1,2,3,4) at position 'B' so the second recursive call will handle moving disc 1,2,3,4 from 'B' to 'C' and will be printed after moving disc 5.

in short, to move discs 1,2,3,4,5 from 'A' to 'C', we have:

```
tower(5,'A','C','B'):
    # perform/print/count all moves to get discs 1,2,3,4 from 'A' to 'B'
    # print/count move disc 5 from 'A' to 'C'
    # perform/print/count all moves to get discs 1,2,3,4 from 'B' to 'C'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
As I said, I'm still learning, so I still have dificulties visualizing the steps from other codes...
As your code worked, now I'm gonna understand why you did it this way, and why it works.
Thanks again for the help!